# Gradle: obfuscate manually on a jar file

Tags: android, gradle, jar, obfuscation

I am using android studio and I want to build a jar file.

The followings should be done:

- exclude some packages and some classes
- exclude some external libraries (jar files have been added to android project)
- and finally and the most important part is obfuscating remaining classes after excluding some classes.

What I have done:

For external libraries i used provided instead of compile and it works well.

```
dependencies {
    provided files('libs/MyLib.jar')
}
```

I defined a jar task to packaging up the codes as follows:

```
task jar(type: Jar) {
from ('build/intermediates/classes/release/')
into ('build/libs/')

exclude ('package/MainActivity.class')
exclude ('package/MyClass.class')
exclude "com.**"

archiveName 'generated_lib.jar'}
```

these task works as expected as well.

For obfuscation, minifyEnabled changed to true for release

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Problem:

obfuscating is being done before excluding classes and libs.

Question:

Is there a way to define a task to do the obfuscation manually after jar task on the jar file?

Or maybe I'm on the wrong track! any suggestion on the requirements would be appreciated.